# What is the best virtualization tool available?

Tags: virtualization

Recently my team has spent too many hours setting up machines with previous product releases or database servers with specific patches. In some cases, we have taken a developers machine down for up three days as a result. Clearly, this would be an ideal case for using a virtual machine. I am trying to champion the practice of making a virtual image of customer releases. I've used VMware effectively in the past for development and testing purposes, but I was wondering if anyone had any other virtualization tools they have had good experience using?

We are doing development in Java on Windows XP machines.

Comment: Perhaps I should also plug my (sort of) related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243716/how-do-you-organize-vmware-workstation-images here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VMWare](http://www.vmware.com) is the best out there IMHO.

Comment: Especially since they got their free and easy to use VMWare Player out.

Comment: I've used VMware Workstation for years, the vms ran nicely. However, one thing that never worked out of the box was the installation of the VMware kernel modules on the host (at least back then). There was always something that could not be compiled, so a patch had to be found. In some cases, one patch did not work, but after some more googling, another one turned up. And not just once, after almost every host kernel update, the VMware modules had to be patched. I'm now using VirtualBox and it's just wonderful how seamlessly it integrates (host update also takes care of VB modules).

Answer (score 5):

I've had great experiences with VirtualBox http://www.virtualbox.org/, and I love that it's free.

Comment: I have tried VirtualBox 2 times (installing Linux on a Virtual Box running in Windows) and both times I had problems. I eventually gave up on it in favor of VMWare, which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: When did you try VirtualBox? The latest versions are nothing short of amazing.

Comment: Same here, I used Virtualbox for some time and I'm quite happy with it

Comment: @schonarth since VirtualBox 2.0 came out very recently, I can't see myself going back. You might give the new version a try.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv.aspx) is actually pretty good (assuming of course you're using Microsoft servers.)

We're actually getting slightly better performance out of it than we did with vmware.

Answer (score 1):

For running Windows VMs on Windows, you can use the MS Virtual PC freeware.

But if you'll ever want Linux, it will fail miserably and not tell you it's because.
In this case, go for VMWare. If you are concerned about the price, there are VMWare workstations and servers. The VMWare Server is pretty much the same as the workstation, but allows having remote VMs. OTOH it doesn't have multiple snapshots (one is all you get) and clipboard integration with host OS. But it's free =)

Answer (score 1):

To second Eric's comment about VirtualBox: not only is it free but it doesn't load processes (i.e., bloat) to your host OS as VMWare does. VMWare slowed down my bootup even in a day in which **I wasn't going to launch it at all.**

VirtualBox also seems **much** faster at launching a VM and much better at translating the graphics/keystrokes to and from the VM, both on Ubuntu Desktop and on Windows XP. My guest XP is almost as fast as my host XP, it seems...

Getting the networking and file sharing and all that stuff to work is a cinch if the guest is Windows XP as in your case (for Linux, it's not as easy).

Answer (score 1):

I've very good experiences with using Citry XenServer. It's free, has many Templates and runs on more Hardware then VMWare. The are also tools like P2V and it's all for Free (at least the Express Edition).

http://citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=683148

Answer (score 0):

We use VMWare ESX 3.5 and are very pleased with it.

Answer (score -1):

I am just starting with virtualization...i am using the book Microsoft Virtualization 4.6...Its been pretty helpful till now...u can check it out..may be you'll find what u looking for...
the link is https://www.packtpub.com/getting-started-microsoft-application-virtualization-46/book

cheers!!

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. 
It would be better if you explained the contents of the link.