# Software for virtualised dev environment

Tags: testing, virtualization

I want to set up my dev machine to run multiple VMs in parallel for development and testing purposes.

Host environment:

- Intel i7-930 (3.8GHz / 8 threads)
- 12GB RAM

Constraints:

- Virtualisation software should have an API with support for basic operations:

  - clone VM
  - start/stop/reset
- Must have configurable virtual hardware
- Must be free or at least reasonably priced (<1000USD)

Based on what I have read, Windows 8 will be shipping with most (if not all) of the features I need, but I would like a system I can use in the short term.

*Note:* I understand the subject of this question has overlap with ServerFault, but I am specifically interested in a solution to run on *my* machine, *not* in a corporate environment.

Comment: As you can see from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265726/what-is-the-best-virtualization-tool-available), this is not constructive, as it calls for opinion and speculation. Voting to close as such.

Comment: @KenWhite How should I improve it? I have said what the intended use is. I have said what the constraints are. I don't care if it gets moved to another SE site, I just want information.

Comment: If you have a dedicated PC, try [standalone Hyper-V Server, which is free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Versions_and_variants). I guess you only pay for Windows licenses in the VMs. Linux in VMs is also supported.

Comment: @Alex I don't have a dedicated PC. As mentioned in the question - I need to be able to run this on *my* dev PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), which AFAIK has all these features. And it's free.

Comment: Thanks. Satisfies constraints 2 and 3. Looking into API docs, but looks like I should be able to use it.